# Using css to customise highcharts in Ionic 4

Tags: highcharts, sass, ionic4

I am using ionic 4 with Highcharts. Everything is working perfectly apart from me not being able to customise the charts through my component's css. I've tried a couple of things but cannot get it to work.

Is there anything I should be adding in the scss to make it be applied on the graph?

A summary of the component:

In my component.ts:

```
import * as HighCharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
    styleUrls: ['./component.scss'],    
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'component.html'
})
```

In my component.html:

```
 <div id="container" style="display: block;"></div>
```

In my component.scss:

```
   .highcharts-loading {
      background: silver;
    }
    .highcharts-loading-inner {
      color: blue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can add styles only globally. So inside **angular-cli.json** add CSS file for the chart - example below `chart-styles.css`:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": ["assets", "favicon.ico"],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": ["styles.css", "chart-styles.css"],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want to use only CSS styles to style your chart you can enable `styled mode`:

```
  chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      styledMode: true
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- style mode: https://codesandbox.io/s/cqxuh
- https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-3v41p

**Docs:**

- https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css

Answer (score 0):

in Highcharts you need to use useHTML property to make things happen.
I'm not familiar with ionic but I had the same issue and the following helped

`plotOptions: { series: { dataLabels: { useHTML: true, } } }`